# How do I get the path of the downloaded Youtube-DL file?

Tags: youtube-dl

I have designed a script to easily and quickly download videos from YouTube that uses options at the end to ask if you want to download another.

Here's my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Videos

read -p "Enter A Valid YouTube URL: "  url

reset

youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4' $url

reset

while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to download another? " yn
    case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) reset; cd ~/Desktop; ./Youtube-DL-Video.sh;;       
    [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

**My Goal**

I'd like to add an option to play the file it just downloaded (Via OMXPlayer).

Is there any command the Youtube-DL has that would give the download path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`youtube-dl` has the `--output` option which allows you to set the output destination:

> **-o, --output** TEMPLATE
> Output filename template, see the "[OUTPUT TEMPLATE](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template)" for all the info

As an example, I use the following template

```
--output "$XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR/youtube/%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

which downloads the video to a `youtube` folder in my download directory and use the video title as filename.

In order to add an option to play the file you just downloaded you can use `--get-filename` option which does not download the video but only returns the filename corresponding to your template:

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4' -o <insert_your_ template_here> $url
file=$(youtube-dl -o <insert_your_template_here> --get-filename)
...
<video_player> $file
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for. I'll try it in a little bit, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to play video from the web through omxplayer to take benefit of the Raspberry Pi hardware acceleration.

You can use youtube-dl to get the URL of the actual video, and then stream it with omxplayer (or vlc which is even more handy for playback and which is also accelerated).

Here is an alias I use:

```
alias omxstream='_(){ omxplayer `youtube-dl --get-url --format best[ext=mp4]/best $1`; };_'
```

You can also do this with a function, if you want to use more code around the simple piped commands:

```
function replay {
    if test -z $1 ; then
        echo -e "No arguments specified. Usage:\n${FUNCNAME[0]} replay-web-page-url"
        return 1
    fi
    # both omxplayer and vlc are hardware accelerated on Raspberry Pi
    vlc --fullscreen `youtube-dl --get-url --format best[ext=mp4]/best $1`
}
```

There is also the possibility to do it with a script.

For the record, this is from my [current version of `.bash_aliases`](https://github.com/jesus2099/settei/blob/470218ae4be0d62a14c80a092afe9cb180b6fbbb/Raspberry%20Pi/.bash_aliases) file.